# Have all the permissions in Instagram Graph API but still getting do not have permission for business_discover endpoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to get the insights of other Instagram public pages through business_discovery endpoint of Instagram Graph API. I have made all the necessary requirements, but when I am hitting the API it returns with:

> "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",

Trying to hit : [https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841405309211845?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841405309211845?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle)%7Bfollowers_count,media_count%7D&access_token=)

Access-Token using : I am using the Grapgh API Explorer's access token.

*I have tried with me and this id its not working.*

Full Error :

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
        "fbtrace_id": "Al9SGP7XBJm0CyqP3MCB0p4"
    }
}
```

I tried changing the id that is placed after v19.0 but it gives different error. Please I need to get insights. I am new to these Instagraph API's. Please help and guide what to do next.

Comment: _"I tried changing the id"_ - change it to - what? This needs to be the ID of the requesting user.